# Name from a list after checking a aleatory number

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot. Now, I'm trying to add a character generator command to it, with name, age and occupation. Having that in mind, its really hard to imagine someone who is 60 as a high school student, so I need to choose occupations based on the aleatory age.

For occupations I made 2 lists, one for 25 or less, and one for 26 or more. Then, when the age, which is aleatory, is 25 or less, will take the occupation from 25less list. How do I do that? I tried this:

```
@client.command()
async def personagem(ctx):
  idade = random.randint(5,60)
  if idade < 20: ocupacao = random.choice(ocupacao18)
  await ctx.send(f'`Nome:{random.choice(nomesh)} {random.choice(sobrenomeh)}\nIdade: {idade}\nOcupação: {random.choice(ocupacao)}`')
```

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aleatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution just need a few adjustements:

```
@client.command()
async def personagem(ctx):
  idade = random.randint(5,60)
  ocupacao = random.choice(ocupacao18) if idade<=25 else random.choice(ocupacaoX)
  await ctx.send(f'`Nome:{random.choice(nomesh)} {random.choice(sobrenomeh)}\nIdade: {idade}\nOcupação: {ocupacao}`')
```

`OcupacaoX` represents the occupations list for people who are above 25.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use of a dictionary! you could do something like this!

```py
import random

job_dictionary = {
    '25_below':['cashier','student','delivery drivery'],
    '26_above':['doctor','lawyer','dentist']
}

user_age=25

if user_age < 26:
    print(random.choice(job_dictionary['25_below']))
else:
    print(random.choice(job_dictionary['26_above']))
```

Keep in mind this code doesn't fit your example, this is just to show roughly how you can use a dictionary here!